# Как добавить slider при добавлении новой строки в datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

Я делаю приложение график отпусков. Задумка в том, что при добавлении ФИО нового человека в таблицу, справа от него должен появляться slider, с помощью которого я уже смогу регулировать дату убытия в отпуск и, соответственно, дату прибытия из него. Так вот, вопрос в следующем : как я смогу сделать так, чтобы при доволен новой строки в datagrid у меня появлялся новый элемент?

Comment: *Справа от него* — это в отдельной колонке DataGrid?

Comment: Нужна иллюстрация, иначе непонятно о каком слайдере идет речь.

Comment: @Андрей NOP  да, в отдельной колонке

Comment: Ну так сделайте шаблон для этой колонки, в него положите Slider